# Using goBack function from react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

Having upgraded from es2015 to 2017th version ive got all my browserHistory.goBack stopped working.

having tried almost anything found on the internet i still cant make it working.

Code:

```
import { goBack } from 'react-router-redux'      

let Popup = () => {
  <a onClick={ goBack }></a>
}
```

exactly same thing used to work with browserHistory.goBack. goBack instead just does nothing.

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <MainLayout>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}  />
        <Popup>
            <Route path="/login"    component={LoginContainer} />
        </Popup>
      </MainLayout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

Popup has goBack button. To show login screen i use  link from Home screen.

Used versions:

> ```
> "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
> "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
> "react-router": "^4.0.0",
> "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
> ```

History creation:

```
const browserHistory = createHistory();
const historyMiddleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);
const middleware = [ thunk, historyMiddleware];
const store = createStore(reducers, preloadedState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

Respectively historyMiddleware is then added into store using applyMiddleware.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What version of React Router are you using?

Comment: @RafaelBerro, just edited a question

Comment: Fine, can you show me how you are creating the history?

Comment: @RafaelBerro, updated the quetion. It should not affect the workflow, but i use server rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history objects to change the current location of your app with several of its methods, such as history.goBack, and the history object is passed down as a prop to Router component's children. So what you can do is in your Popup component:

```
let Popup = ({children}) => {
  <button onClick={ children.props.history.goBack }></button>
}
```

However, props.history and context.history are deprecated. You should use context.router instead

UPDATE::
To use context.router

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
   render(){
     <button onClick={ this.context.router.goBack }></button>
   }
}

Popup.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Popup
```

UPDATE 2::

My test application setup

```
//Index.js
import { createDevTools } from 'redux-devtools'
import LogMonitor from 'redux-devtools-log-monitor'
import DockMonitor from 'redux-devtools-dock-monitor'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

import * as reducers from './reducers'
import { App, Home, Foo, Bar } from './components'

const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...reducers,
  routing: routerReducer
})

const DevTools = createDevTools(
  <DockMonitor toggleVisibilityKey="ctrl-h" changePositionKey="ctrl-q">
    <LogMonitor theme="tomorrow" preserveScrollTop={false} />
  </DockMonitor>
)

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  DevTools.instrument()
)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
          <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
          <Route path="bar" component={Bar}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
      <DevTools />
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('mount')
)

//App.js
import React from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        Links:
        {' '}
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        {' '}
        <Link to="/foo">Foo</Link>
        {' '}
        <Link to="/bar">Bar</Link>
        <button onClick={this.context.router.goBack}>Back</button>}
      </header>
    </div>
  )
  }
}

App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App
```

Comment: How could i use context.router for my case?

Comment: in first case children has a collection of routes and therefore does not have props property. A second (correct) scenario does nothing, no goBack fired, but not exceptions too. Context has router set, but goBack function is undefined.

Comment: Ok, an issue with second (correct) scenario is goBack function is part of history object and therefore it should be this.context.router.history.goBack.

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: You sure your browserHistory is working correctly and your middlewares are in place?

Comment: I think so. Please check original post update section for middleware use.

Comment: Hmm not sure why an object tree is different for us two. You import browserHistory from package, i create it using createHistory().

Comment: As of v4 it appears to now be: `this.context.router.history.goBack`